# Test in a Bash script if the user can input data using `read` or equivalent

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to know if the user can input data.

In a script, it is usually possible to call `read -r VARIABLE` to request input from the user. However, this doesn't work in all environments: for example, in CI scripts, it's not possible for the user to input anything, and I'd like to substitute a default value in that case.

So far, I'm handling this with a timeout, like this:

```
echo "If you are a human, type 'ENTER' now. Otherwise, automatic installation will start in 10 seconds..."
read -t 10 -r _user_choice || _user_choice="no-user-here"
```

But honestly, that just looks ugly.

The solution doesn't have to use `read`, however it needs to be portable to all major distros that have Bash, so it's not possible to use packages that are not installed by default.

Comment: what is a CI script?

Comment: Continuous Integration, basically automated tests that run on another server; there's no user there so scripts cannot be interactive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
$ cat stdin.bash
if [[ -t 0 ]]; then
    echo "stdin is a terminal, so the user can input data"
else
    echo "stdin is connected to some other redirect or pipeline"
fi
```

and, demonstrating

```
$ bash stdin.bash
stdin is a terminal, so the user can input data

$ echo foo | bash stdin.bash
stdin is connected to some other redirect or pipeline
```

From `help test` output:

> ```
>   -t FD          True if FD is opened on a terminal.
> ```